# Sum relationship column before pagination in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table that has products with price and a second table that has discounts with amount column. What I am looking for is a total of all products prices and all discounts amount from the query.The discount relation is a **belongsTo**

I am using the following to get my total product prices before my pagination.

```
$query->with(['discount']);

$total_cost = $query->sum('price');

$products = $query->paginate(25);
```

It works great for getting the **$total_cost** but I can't figure out how to get discounts and sum the **amount** column.

Comment: you can clone original object before `sum` like `$query = $query->with(['discount]);` then `$queryClone = clone $query`; then you can sum 2 different columns with the original and clone object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concept of eager loading with relationship will help with that.

```
$query->with(['discount' => function($another_query) {
    $another_query->// do your sum here
} ]);
```